# For some reason my account is gone

Tags: support, accounts

I had this account: https://stackexchange.com/users/3623090/snaggs **2K rep.**

I used my regular gmail account to login.

I didn't enter last few month but when I tried to login again, I got other account: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4415175/snaggs (since 2015) **13 rep.**

What should I do?

Comment: Probably best to use the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) link and ask for an account merge. SE staff has a process in place to verify the other account belongs to you and execute the merge.

Comment: You used two different gmail addresses, one starting with S another with W. Instructions to merge: https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts